# What would "http://crl.microsoft.com/pki/crl/products/CSPCA.crl" be used for?

Tags: windows-networking

I have seen this on the network report from 2 high school students that were playing "unautherized" games. It displays a certificate revocation list... how would that help them?

Answer (score 0):

You are reading a report of all sites that the program contacted while they were running the game?  Most likely, it is part of the authentication method used by the game, and is automatically requested by the program.  It's not something they were querying themselves.  It doesn't help them, so much as protect the game environment from systems that are known to be compromised.

CRL's are used in [Public Key Infrastructures (PKI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_infrastructure) to ensure that someone can't use a stolen or expired certificate.